# npm throws some error in visual studio code while trying to run it

Tags: reactjs

Whenever i try to run npm, it throws following error in vs code terminal :

PS D:\reactjs> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\reactjs\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\reactjs\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-04T12_10_00_086Z-debug.log

Comment: Are you running npm start in the correct directory? Sounds like you are missing package.json from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your current path and in your current directory do you have `package.json` or not.